# Error Domain Name onlinethailandbooking.com Does Not Exist In The Database

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am shifting my Website to another server.

i take the back up of both the website and database also. now when i configured it on new server it first shows the upgrade to database and then shows the error of

Domain Name onlinethailandbooking.com Does Not Exist In The Database

DotNetNuke supports multiple portals from a single database/codebase. It accomplishes this by converting the URL of the client browser Request to a valid PortalID in the Portals database table. The following steps describe the process:

```
Web Server Processing
    When a web server receives a Request from a client browser, it compares the file name extension on the target URL resource to its Application Extension Mappings defined in IIS.
    Based on the corresponding match, IIS then sends the Request to the defined Executable Path ( aspnet_asapi.dll in the case of ASP.NET Requests ).
    The aspnet_isapi.dll engine processes the Request in an ordered series of events beginning with Application_BeginRequest.


HttpModule.URLRewrite OnBeginRequest ( UrlRewriteModule.vb )
    The Request URL is parsed based on the "/" character
    A Domain Name is constructed using each of the relevant parsed URL segments.

    Examples:

    URL: http://www.domain.com/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com
    URL: http://209.75.24.131/default.aspx = Domain Name: 209.75.24.131
    URL: http://localhost/DotNetNuke/default.aspx = Domain Name: localhost/DotNetNuke
    URL: http://www.domain.com/virtualdirectory/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com/virtualdirectory
    URL: http://www.domain.com/directory/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com/directory

    Using the Domain Name, the application queries the database ( Portals table - PortalAlias field ) to locate a matching record.

    Note: If there are multiple URLs which correspond to the same portal then the PortalAlias field must contain each valid Domain Name in a comma seperated list.

    Example:

    URL: http://localhost/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
    URL: http://MACHINENAME/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
    URL: http://209.32.134.65/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
    PortalAlias: localhost/DotNetNuke,MACHINENAME/DotNetNuke,209.32.134.65/DotNetNuke

    Note: If you are installing the application to a remote server you must modify the PortalAlias field value for the default record in the Portals table according to the rules defined above.
```

I look into the database dbo.portalalises but there is only 2 entries of portal but i have 3 portals..i think it can't generates the portal id automatically?

how this error be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your permissions on your web folders match those of the AppPool your site runs under on the new host
2. Verify your database connection and permissions
3. Verify that your entry in the PortalAlias table in the database is correct for your new host

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, I had the same issue, after I made sure that I have updated the "Portal Alias" table in db, to have a HTTP Alias (for my local host, I set it to localhost:8089 which was equal to what I had set up in IIS binding for DNN website), with the portal ID of 0 (as my portal id was 0), I was checking to be sure I have updated web.config file with data base connection strings, but then I realized there were two points for database connection in web.config, and I was missing one of them. So make sure to update both two connections as:

```
1) <connectionStrings>
2) <appSettings>
```

Hope this helps.